# XAML previewer for Visual Studio 2015. Is it available or are there any third party alternatives?

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2015

I am coming from android studio and am really missing the preview feature when editting XML code.

The Xamarin website says this: 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/

I find it essential to use the XML preview because I am still a beginner and learning.

Is there any way this can be done? Perhaps any third party apps if they exist?

Thanks In advance

Comment: If you come from Android Studio, then Xamarin already has full Android visual designer in VS. You only need the XAML Previewer if you are writing Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: @LexLi I like to see what each line of xml code does when I type it, a real-time render of what is happening. Unfortunately, a preview feature has not been implemented for Xamarin yet, so I can only see the adjustments by moving back and forth between Design and Source views, which can get annoying because the renders take a some time.

Answer (score 1):

There some alternatives to Xamarin's own XAML previewers, but it is unclear whether those third parter alternatives would support XAML themes.

1. Gorilla Player

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFvVR.png)
This one is particularly good for previewing the XAML live simultaneously across multiple platform. I think its available on windows but the level of integration with visual studio remains unclear. However, as their download page contains link for windows, it should support it.

You can access it from this link: 
http://gorillaplayer.com

2. XenForms

XenForms is another promising Xamarin.Forms. You can Load, Edit, and Save XAML. This is the first WYSIWYG UI designer for Xamarin.Forms. This tool definitely support windows as a developing platform and windows phones. Unfortunately, it does NOT support drag and drop. Another great feature is that is it has some support for c# user interface as well as the XAML markups.www.xenforms.com

Comment: Thank you for those links! I shall try them out as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can check Xamarin's own previewer which is integrated with Visual Studio. Please update your xamarin to latest installation. You may also need to rebuild the solution and then open/reopen the XAML file for preview. For details please check my [blog post here](https://foyzulkarim.wordpress.com/2017/02/28/xamarin-forms-previewer/).